# How to assign a variable of type Double to an Integer type one?

Tags: pascal

I would like to assign a `Double` to `Integer` variable on Scar Divi, which uses Pascal.
Here's an example:

```
program Test;       
var
  dou: Double;
  int: Integer; 
begin
  int := 1;
  dou := 2.5;

  dou := Trunc(dou);

  int := int + dou;
end.
```

Console gives me a `Type mismatch`. How to assign a variable of type `Double` to an `Integer` type one ?

Comment: `int := int + Integer(dou);`

Comment: No. I also tried. Type Mismatch.

Comment: ``int := int + Trunc(dou);``

Comment: It works! Thanks. `int := int + Trunc(dou);`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
dou := Trunc(dou); {dou is still a variable of type double}

int := int + dou;  {adding double to integer returns double,
                    which cannot be assigned to integer -> ERROR}
```

type:

```
int := int + Trunc(dou); {adding integer to integer gives integer -> OK}
```

Also note that in some cases `Round`, which returns the nearest integer, may be better than `Trunc`.